# Is it possible to embed 3D data into XSL-FO?

Tags: pdf, 3d, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

**Setup**

- XSL processor: Saxon
- FO processor / PDF renderer: Antenna House Formatter V6.2

Is it possible to embed a 3D PDF, XVL or 3DU via a FO transformation / PDF rendering into the current publication?

The source data would have several XML, XVL (whatever) 3D data nodes that have to be processed into the generated PDF.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed a 3D PDF using AH Formatter V6.2 or V6.3.  Use `fo:external-graphic` to refer to the PDF just as you would for any other external image.

In the AH Formatter GUI, you can select to embed 3D annotations in the 'PDF Option Setting' dialog box (see https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf60/docs/ahf-gui.html#others-page). On the `AHFCmd` (or `run.sh` on Linux/Unix) command line, you may need to specify `-p3da`  (see https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf60/docs/ahf-xslcmd.html#keyIDAR1YD) and/or enable 3D annotations in the Option Setting File (see https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf60/docs/ahf-optset.html#keyIDAVUFU).

Comment: thank you. that would mean that the 3d data to pdf rendering process has already happened and I am then embedding the 3D PDF (and not the raw data), right? a suitable tool for this could be Adobe Acrobat 3D.

Comment: Yes, you would have to generate the 3D PDF using some other tool.  Sorry, but I can't help you there.